# problem with facebook api - Keeps redirecting

Tags: php, facebook

I created an application with a  name and connect URL on facebook.

I put below code  in test.php here (test.php):

```
include_once 'facebook.php';
$fb = new Facebook('api_key', 'secret');
$user = $fb->require_login();
echo $fb->api_client->user;    
echo $fb->api_client->session_key;
```

when I go to that page, it takes me to facebook login, after I login it redirects me to same test.php with an `auth_token`. But it doesn't stop there. For some reason, the script is taking me to facebook again and since I already logged in facebook redirecting me to test.php with another auth_token just like below

```
/test.php?auth_token=76a6eb21b872cdfe787ea85a240905dd&auth_token=597d7532bf53c8ce37cc003bcf7d2905
```

It never stops there, test.php taking me to facebook again and again :(

Please tell me what wrong??

Thanks a lot

Comment: i doubt  that anyone will voluntarily test your application why allowing it to pull everything from their profile.

post your tests.php code here.

Comment: latest FB SDK do not have 'require_login()' method. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

adda line:
`$facebook->require_frame();`